# Why are query lost after clicking to jump to a new page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Description of the problem:
When clicking on the third-level category, it will be redirected to the homepage. This is not a redirection problem, but a problem of losing parameters. I have tried it, and after removing the redirect code in route.js, the page will appear blank and the path becomes http://localhost:8080/#/.

Context of the problem and methods tried:
The path of the redirection is correct, as shown in the figure. Manually adding parameters can jump normally.

[image]

Before using this.router.push to jump, print the parameters and found no problem, as shown in the figure.

[image]

code：
Type.vue：

```
if (categoryname) {
        let location = {
          name:'search',
          query:{categoryName:categoryname},
        };
        if (category1id) {
          location.query.category1Id=category1id;
        } else if (category2id) {
          location.query.category2Id = category2id;
        } else {
          location.query.category3Id = category3id;
        }
        if(this.$route.params.keyword){
          location.params = this.$route.params;
        }
        this.$router.push(location);
      }
```

route.js：

```
    {
        path: "/home",
        component: Home,
        meta:{show:true},
    },
    {
        name:"search",
        path:"/search/:keyword?",
        component:Search,
        meta:{ show:true },
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect:"/home"
    },
]
```

Search.vue：

```
watch:{
      $route(newValue,oldValue){
        Object.assign( this.searchParams, this.$route.query, this.$route.params )
        this.getData()
        //  把相应的1，2，3级分类的id清空
        this.searchParams.category1Id = ''
        this.searchParams.category2Id = ''
        this.searchParams.category3Id = ''
      }
    },
```

i hope to click on the third-level category and have it jump normally, instead of being redirected to the home page or http://localhost:8080/#/.